# PHP Ucwords on underscores

Tags: php

Just curious if anyone knows a quick way to use ucwords() on a string replacining
underscores with spaces? I have a preg_replace that will do it, but won't add the 
needed spaces in between...

```
// this_string_contents -> ThisStringContents
preg_replace('/(?:^|_)(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')",$string);
```

And the reverse

```
// ThisStringContents -> this_string_contents
strtolower(preg_replace('/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/', "$1_$2", $string));
```

It would be nice if these were symmetrical too, the above
will do something like this

```
* this_is_a_string -> ThisIsAString -> this_is_astring
* GetURLForString -> get_urlfor_string -> GetUrlforString
```

Comment: ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $string))

Comment: CakePHP has a great Inflector class. [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1479/Class-methods) - [API (with source)](http://api11.cakephp.org/class_inflector.html)

Comment: Zend Framework has a couple of filter to achieve this: http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Filter/Word/

Comment: or `$The_String_Contents = implode('_', array_map('ucwords', explode('_', 'the_string_contents')));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex if you don't have to- use `str_replace` instead.

```
str_replace('_', ' ', $string);
```